# The Giant List of Duplicates

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, big-list

For those who haven't been frequenting meta, this post has been [suggested](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3433/) [numerous](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3409/) [times](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3229?m=32623774#32623774). The intention is to collect together *good* questions with *good* answers which can be used as duplicate targets. While this is obviously a mammoth task, there is no stipulation that it is (or ever will be) exhaustive. I invite everybody to contribute to this - if you come across a good question (with a good answer) on the main site, add it here!

### Contents

The organisation is not quite finalised, this is what I think works out well (glanced through university course structure) but we can always see how things go and adapt. Some links could perhaps be move into or out of basic stuff.

- [**Inorganic chemistry**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3473/)
- Nomenclature
- Atomic properties and trends
- Acid-base theories
- Theories of molecular bonding
- Main group chemistry
- Transition metal and coordination chemistry
- Solid state chemistry
- [**Organic chemistry**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3474/)
- Nomenclature
- Spectrometry
- Stereochemistry and conformational analysis
- Mechanisms and mechanistic detail
- Reactions and synthesis
- [**Physical chemistry**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3475/)
- Thermodynamics
- Chemical kinetics
- Quantum mechanics and spectroscopy
- Molecular symmetry
- Statistical mechanics
- Electronic structure theory
- Intermolecular interactions
- Molecular dynamics
- [**Basic concepts**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3694/)
- Hypervalent menace
- Stoichiometry
- Oxidation numbers
- Other

Comment: I think the key must be here, that the questions in this list shall be canonical, i.e. they must have and answer which is easily transferred to a different task because of the same concept. Like *"What is the pH of 0.1 M acetic acid?"* or *"What is the pH of 2M ammonia?"* should be marked duplicates of *"How to calculate the pH of a weak acid or base?"*

Comment: @Martin-マーチン So, is it the plan, then, to consider questions that are a more-specific version of a general, canonical question, to be duplicates of that general, canonical question? On first reaction, I think this is fine; just clarifying.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks, I forgot to mention that aspect. Thanks, I will edit it in some time (bad jet lag right now..) @hBy2Py That is the direction we want to move in for various reasons.

Comment: I mean, it makes great sense -- I'd much rather close Q's like that as duplicates, because then it both (a) gets the question cleared away and (b) points the OP at something that will hopefully help them get the info they need.

Comment: Also, if a canonical question and answer pair do not yet exist, anyone is certainly invited to create one!

Comment: There should probably be another answer for "miscellaneous" chemistry, i.e. biochemistry, analytical chemistry, computational chemistry, ...

Answer (score 14):

## Organic chemistry

### Nomenclature

- [Loong's nomenclature answers, to be ordered by Blue Book section, one day when I feel up to it...](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/1374243) I've done all the oldest answers, up until and including the "smallest sum of locants" question. (...Now there's a [separate list question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4990/list-of-loongs-nomenclature-answers) about them!)
- P-14.3.5 [IUPAC nomenclature: "Smallest sum of locants"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27095) and direct applications of this rule: [1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24768/), [2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27816)
- P-29.2 [How should I name this branched alkyl substituent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49058)
- P-45.2.1 [Alkane nomenclature - choosing the parent chain - maximize or minimize substituents?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19313)
- P-45.2.3 [Alphabetization rule in case of consecutively placed substituents](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68624)
- P-52.2.8 [Is the ring or the chain chosen as the parent structure in octan-2-ylbenzene?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19229) and maybe duplicate: [1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27584)

### Spectrometry

- [Why does the carbonyl group in an acid anhydride have two stretching frequencies?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42919)
- [Why is tetramethylsilane (TMS) used as an internal standard in NMR spectroscopy?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47913)

### Acidity and basicity

- [Relative acidities of alkanes, alkenes, and alkynes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32341)

### Stereochemistry and conformational analysis

- [Can heteroatoms with lone pairs be chiral centres?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50106)
- [Is cis-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane a meso compound?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/61107)
- [Chirality of substituted adamantanes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58727)
- [Why is 1-ethylidene-4-methylcyclohexane chiral?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58630)

### Mechanisms and mechanistic detail

- [How do organic chemistry mechanisms become accepted?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/65044)
- [Addition of hydrogen bromide to 1,3-butadiene: thermodynamic and kinetic control](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59964)
- [Why does LiAlH4 reduce an amide to an amine, but only reduce a ketone/aldehyde to an alcohol?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50534)
- [Mechanism for oxidation of primary alcohols to carboxylic acids](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43283)
- [Regioselectivity in radical chlorination of a carboxylic acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49850)
- **Wittig reaction** [Mechanism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/65233) | [*Z*-selective (unstabilised)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5313) | [*E*-selective (stabilised)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81763)

### Reactions and synthesis

- [How can I predict if a reaction will occur between any two (or more) substances?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50684/)

Answer (score 11):

## Inorganic chemistry

### Nomenclature

- [Why is methane's molecular formula conventionally "CH₄", while water is "H₂O" (among others)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/974/)
- [How to name binary (inorganic) compounds given their chemical formula, and vice-versa?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98159/how-to-name-binary-inorganic-compounds-given-their-chemical-formula-and-vice)

### Qualitative Analysis

- [Method and Tips for Inorganic Qualitative Analysis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49673/)

### Atomic properties and periodic trends

- [Melting and boiling points of transition elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4766/)

### Acid-base theories

- [Does H3O+ donate a H+ to Water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14117)
- [How should the hydrated proton be represented in chemical equations?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/20076)

### Theories of molecular bonding

- [Why is an S-S bond stronger than an O-O bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47056/)
- [Molecular orbital diagram for BF3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/80247/)

### Main group chemistry

- [Why do the alkali metals form different products upon combustion in air?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50796)
- [Enthalpies of formation of alkali metal halides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42157)
- [Why is lithium the most reducing alkali metal, and not caesium?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28568)
- [Why do compounds like SF6 and SF4 exist but SH6 and SH4 don't?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4760)
- [Why are bromine oxyanions uncommon?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49596)
- [Why is the inversion barrier larger in PH3 than it is in NH3?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38599)
- [Bond angles for the hydrides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33818/)

### Transition metal chemistry

- [Cr(II) and Mn(III) - their oxidizing and reducing properties?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/45153)
- [How can the intense color of potassium permanganate be explained with molecular orbital theory?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39829)
- [Why is [PdCl4]2- square planar whereas [NiCl4]2- is tetrahedral?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40880)
- [Why is WF6 stable whereas CrF6 is unknown?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48971)

### Solid state chemistry

- [What does β stand for in β-potassium zirconate?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/67239)
- [Why are there only 7 types of unit cells and 14 types of Bravais lattices?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35273)
- [What are Lattice Points?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15089)

Answer (score 9):

## Physical chemistry

### Thermodynamics

- [What is the difference between ∆G and ∆G°?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/41862)
- [Can the change in internal energy be nonzero if temperature is constant?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39645)
- [Relation between constant-pressure and constant-volume heat capacities: Cp - Cv = nR](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59618)
- [Derivation of van 't Hoff equation for temperature dependence of equilibrium constant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32385)
- [Why does the Gibbs free energy only correspond to non-expansion work?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32873)
- [Deriving a reduction potential from two other reduction potentials](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9454/)
- [Enthalpy definitions. What are their main differences?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/72930/)

### Chemical kinetics

- [Do coefficients matter in rate law?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38167)
- [Relation between Gibbs energy and net reaction rate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47038)
- [Does a reaction have to have a rate determining step?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42566)

### Quantum mechanics and spectroscopy

- [Derivation of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59822)
- [What is the physical basis for Hund's first rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58625)
- [Why is manganese(II) coloured although the transition should be spin-forbidden?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50436)
- [Letter codes in molecular term symbols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59211)
- [Why don't equivalent hydrogens cause splitting in NMR?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/53478)
- [How to explain the discrepancy between the calculated absorption wavelength within the particle in the box theory and the observed wavelength?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/44676)

### Molecular symmetry/Group Theory

- [How do I determine the molecular vibrations of linear molecules?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/70858)
- [Group theoretical condition for an integral to be zero](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/78760)
- [Using group theory to make molecular orbital diagrams](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/77450)
- [Symmetry representations](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19477)
- [What is the mathematical basis behind the Jahn-Teller effect?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/73923)

### Statistical mechanics

- [What is the physical significance of molecular partition function?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/76730)

### Electronic structure theory

- [Why does the 3rd electron shell start filling up with scandium?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8357)
- [How to find the number of atomic microstates for a given electronic configuration?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37038)

### Intermolecular interactions

- [Trend in the boiling point of the hydrogen halides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43350)

### Molecular dynamics

- 

Answer (score 6):

## Basic stuff

### Hypervalent menace

- [Bonding in the phosphate ion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13657/)
- [How can double compounds like XeO4 form tetrahedral structures despite having double bonds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19836/)
- [How can the Bonding in IF7 be explained using LCAO method?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6785/)

### Stoichiometry

- [Simplest way to balance any chemical equation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10021/)
- [Balancing Chemical Equations](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39549/)
- [Are matrices a good way to do stoichiometry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24245/)

### Oxidation numbers

- [An introduction to "oxidation state"/"oxidation number"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/69798/)
- [What are oxidation states used for?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/61040/)
- [Why is electronegativity increasing with oxidation state increase?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24676/)

### Varia

- [What makes carbon special and versatile?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18843/)
- [What is the definition of organic compounds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6690/)
- [Are metallic/ionic bonds weaker than covalent bonds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/11048/)
- [The pH of a neutralized solution](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19808/)
- [Is it possible to separate/remove sugar from common drinks, such as juice?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40905/)
- [Chemical properties of isotopes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5084/)
- [Simple Explanation of orbitals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40646/)

Answer (score 1):

## Metals and their properties

### Alloys

- [Do we have some "rule of thumb" to estimate the miscibility of metals?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138726/do-we-have-some-rule-of-thumb-to-estimate-the-miscibility-of-metals?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Miscibility of Molten Metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35014/miscibility-of-molten-metals)
- [What are the conditions for liquid metal to be corrosive to another, different solid metal?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32530/what-are-the-conditions-for-liquid-metal-to-be-corrosive-to-another-different-s)
- [What is the chemistry behind amalgamation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16304/what-is-the-chemistry-behind-amalgamation)