# What are the ways to bring attention to a question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Consider the following question: [Why does [Co(NO2)6]4− ion have 3 unpaired electron as opposed to 1?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/90560/why-does-cono264-ion-have-3-unpaired-electron-as-opposed-to-1). I believe this is a great question that was asked quite a lot of time ago and still has no answers. **What are the ways of generating interest on the site with regards to these old questions?**

A few solutions I have encountered are:

- Setting a bounty: This is a good way of bringing attention. However, the risk involved in doing so is quite high. You lose the bounty that you pledge immediately and there is also a chance of not receiving a satisfactory answer within the bounty period.

  - Asking others to set a bounty: [This](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/lets-do-the-bounty-dance/3219) thread seems good but I am not sure if Martin is still accepting nominations here.
- Editing the post: This bumps the question to the top of the queue. However, this is yet to bring results (I tried this tactic with the question I mentioned above, but haven't got anything yet)
- Writing a meta post mentioning this question. Which is what I am doing here ;)

If anyone has any other ways of generating interest regarding these questions, please suggest.

Comment: Posting in active chat rooms can be an option, though I can't guarantee results. Actually I myself have a question that's left unanswered, neither does it have any comments that discuss the issue. I tried editing the post to put it on top of queue, posted on 'Periodic Table', but of no avail. Another point I agree is the *chance of not receiving a satisfactory answer within the bounty period.* One has to lose his rep, to someone who hasn't quite answered the question, but as there weren't better ones, it got the bounty. This seems hurting when it costs a lot but you don't get a good return.

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3698/canonical-qa-proposing-a-patronage-system/3914#3914 This is another question in a similar vein about using meta to have extended bounty periods.

Comment: Meh, all this bring "attention", but your post seems to have meaning "how to get answer" - there's no certain way, but best you can do is answer yourself - you get rep. and additional insight.

Comment: Editing a post to include new details is a definitely good but often users abuse that feature to add trivial details which are an obvious abuse of the active questions feed and is a bad way to gain attention.